# File Lines into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So i want to create a List that contain each Line of a File

```
list = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines() #Input File
i=0
print list[i]
for x in list[i]:
    print x  #the problem is on this line
    i+=1
```

'print x' inside the for loop prints all of the symbols, one by one, in a new line.
Thought it should print the full line as a single list item.
why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `[i]` in the for-loop line:

```
# Don't name a variable 'list' -- it overshadows the built-in
lst = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
i=0
print lst[i]
for x in lst:
    print x
```

Your current code is iterating over the **first line** of the file, not all of the lines.  Remember that `i=0` and `list` is a list of the lines in the file.  So, `list[i]` is the first item in `list` or, namely, the first line in the file.

---

Also, your current code isn't going to close the file.  Hence, it would be best to use [`with`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) here:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as myfile:
    lst = myfile.readlines()
    i=0
    print lst[i]
    for x in lst:
        print x
```

I would strongly recommend that you use `with` every time you open a file since it auto-closes them for you.